# WPF Patterns - Which one should I learn

Tags: .net, wpf, design-patterns

I have got programming experience using the MVC pattern on web applications, I am planing to implement an application to learn WPF, which pattern should I apply?

Which one is the most used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have experience in MVC, then you should certainly learn [**MVVM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), which is a pattern similar to MVC, but adapted to and improved by utilizing the binding, commands, and templating features of WPF.

Comment: MVVM goes hand in hand with WPF

Comment: Like Charlie said, MVVM goes hand in hand with WPF and with SL4 it is doing a really good job even in Silverlight ;)

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is best one for learning; you can also look at Composite WPF(PRISM) from Microsoft Pattern & Practices; It is also used a lot -

http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF

Comment: Prism is exceedingly cool but it doesn't enforce mvvm like you would think. Learning and implementing mvvm _yourself_, prior to using a framework will give you swifter and fuller understanding of how the frameworks work and are intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is the most widely used pattern and recommended in most cases. It allows for unit-testable user interface code plus a methodic way to code applications. I wouldn't do without it for any medium or large application.

If you want to learn quickly about both WPF and the MVVM pattern, read this book: [Learn WPF MVVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M365NCZ).